# cmake check if Mac OS X, use APPLE or ${APPLE}

Tags: cmake

I would like check whether I am in Mac OS X or not, and have the following code

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (test)
set (FOO 1)
if (${FOO} AND ${APPLE})
  message ("MAC OS X")
endif ()
```

It failed on non-OSX system with error message

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "1" "AND"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

If I replace `${APPLE}` with `APPLE`, the error went away. But I am a little puzzled by this. When should we refer to a variable with `${VAR}` and when should we not to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39707772/2799037

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To put it shortly: Everything inside the if parentheses is evaluated as an expression, this is the semantic of the `if` keyword. So if you put `APPLE` there, it gets evaluated as a variable name and yields the correct result.

Now if you put `${APPLE}` there, `${}` will evaluate its contents *before* `if` evaluates the expression. Therefore, it's the same as if you'd written

```
if (1 AND )
```

(in the case that the variable `APPLE` isn't set, which is the case on non-OSX systems). This is invalid syntax and yields the error you get. You should write:

```
if (FOO AND APPLE)
```

Quoting from the [CMake Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html):

> The if command was written very early in CMake’s history, predating the ${} variable evaluation syntax, and for convenience evaluates variables named by its arguments as shown in the above signatures. Note that normal variable evaluation with ${} applies before the if command even receives the arguments. Therefore code like:

```
set(var1 OFF)
set(var2 "var1")
if(${var2})
```

> appears to the if command as:

```
if(var1)
```

> and is evaluated according to the if() case documented above. The result is OFF which is false. However, if we remove the ${} from the example then the command sees:

```
if(var2)
```

> which is true because var2 is defined to “var1” which is not a false constant.

Answer (score 47):

Not 100% relevant but when googling for how to check for OSx in CMake this is the top post. For others who land here asking the same question this worked for me.

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    set(MACOSX TRUE)
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for!

Comment: The CMake mailing lists mentions that this is not technically foolproof: *"Darwin is the Unix underpinnings of OS X and it is Open Source. I could run a Darwin system and have it NOT be OS X."*. Other than `APPLE`, I couldn't find any strong alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

This also works to test for Windows, Mac and *Nix

```
if(WIN32)
   message("https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/WIN32.html?highlight=win32")
elseif(APPLE)
   message("https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/APPLE.html?highlight=apple")
elseif(UNIX)
    message("https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/UNIX.html?highlight=unix")
endif()
```

`APPLE` should be tested before `UNIX` because `UNIX` is set to `true` for Mac OS.

Testing the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` variable, as proposed by @Matthew Hogan allows you to test for something more specific.