# error in cmake IF statement

Tags: cmake

I have a `if` statement in my `.cmake` file which reads like:

```
if( (NOT ${GCC_VERSION} GREATER some_version ) AND something EQUAL somethingelse)
    #todo ...
endif()
```

I need the `NOT` only for the first check of the statement.

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/.../XXX.cmake:123:
Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  Instead found left paren with text "(".
```

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this locally. Which CMake version? Can you provide a stand-alone [mcve]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake error near if: "if given arguments" followed by parantheses, "NOT", "EUQALS" and similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707772/cmake-error-near-if-if-given-arguments-followed-by-parantheses-not-euqal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GCC_VERSION` variable could be empty, resulting in an invalid `if` statement.

Put `${GCC_VERSION}` in quotes (CMake only knows strings) or don't dereference the variable (which is an equivalent operation) to be on the safe side:

```
if( NOT "${GCC_VERSION}" GREATER some_version )
```

or

```
if( NOT GCC_VERSION GREATER some_version )
```

**References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)